# CovrageInfo.CreateFromFile is giving an error

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, code-coverage

I have replicated the code from the example to collect the result for code coverage from [Here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/phuene/archive/2009/12/01/programmatic-coverage-analysis-in-visual-studio-2010.aspx) except that my code is vb.net

Here is my code

```
Imports Microsoft.VisualStudio.Coverage.Analysis


Module Module1

    Sub Main()
        Using info As CoverageInfo = CoverageInfo.CreateFromFile("C:MyFile\data.coverage")

            Dim lines As New List(Of BlockLineRange)()

            For Each [module] As ICoverageModule In info.Modules

                Dim coverageBuffer As Byte() = [module].GetCoverageBuffer(Nothing)
                Using reader As ISymbolReader = [module].Symbols.CreateReader()

                    Dim methodId As UInteger = 0
                    Dim MethodName As String = ""
                    Dim undecoratedMethodName As String = ""
                    Dim ClassName As String = ""
                    Dim NameSpaceName As String = ""

                    lines.Clear()

                    While reader.GetNextMethod(methodId, MethodName, undecoratedMethodName, ClassName, NameSpaceName, lines)

                        Dim stats As CoverageStatistics = CoverageInfo.GetMethodStatistics(coverageBuffer, lines)
                        Console.WriteLine("Method {0}{1}{2}{3}{4} has:" & NameSpaceName & ClassName & undecoratedMethodName)

                        Console.WriteLine(" blocks covered are {0}", stats.BlocksCovered)
                    End While
                End Using
            Next

        End Using
    End Sub

End Module
```

When I run this on the line for `CreateFromFile` i get a `ImageNotFoundException`

```
Image File "C:\SomeAddress\MyServer\UnitTest.dll" could not be found
```

I have already as per instructions added the neccessary dlls to my project copied and the other 2 as references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And yet another tumbleweed moment....

Basically the problem was that folder containing my coverage file also had to contains all the dlls used within that assembely that tests were ran on in order to create that object.

hope this helps you if you ever stumbled over this issuen :)